# Magento - how to filter categories in phtml

Tags: magento, collections, categories, php

I have been working on the maga menu. I got the collection in phtml like:

`<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>`

Now I have to add the filter to show specific categories. Like I have an **array(1,2,3,4)** of categories that i want to show. so how can I apply filter to this Helper.

Any one have any suggestion please answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first answer is correct but it's not efficient as it consumes unnecessary database round trips. @Karan's code issues a query to the database for every id. Just imagine if the number of category ids to be filtered were 50 or above.

My example would be this:

```
<?php

$catIds = array(1,2,3,4);

$catCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('id', $catIds)->addAttributeToFilter('is_active',1);

foreach($catCollection as $category){
  echo $category->getName()." ";
}
```

This will reduce the database roundtrip to just one.

Comment: Yes matte you are right. it reduces the database query trip. thans :)

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
<?php $catids[]=array(1,2,3,4);

 foreach($catids as $id):

                        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);

                     if($_category->getIsActive()):
                            echo $_category->getName();
                     endif;
endforeach;

?>
```

and don't forget to link my answer if it was helpful